# Unable to Start WSL2 machines. Tried Ubuntu 20.04, 18.04 and all

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualization, hyper-v, wsl2

I am not able to start any newly installed WSL2 machines, not sure what the exact problem is on my Windows 10 build. I was using Ubuntu 18.04 till yesterday, but then thought to install new version of WSL2 to use its features, hence uninstalled the previous version of it and installed new one. Tried all solutions from the internet and youtube as well, but nothing worked and since then I am getting this error:

[image]

I have all the required features enabled such as Virtualization, Hyper-V and rest.

Here is my system configuration:

Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on ‎12/‎13/‎2019
OS build 19042.450
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Virtualization: Enabled

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIa4p.png)

[image]

My Current WSL1 Machines are working fine. I ran all commands to run WSL2 but still facing the issue.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot does not indicate if `Virtual Machine Platform` is enabled.  Please edit your question to include which optional Windows Features are installed.   **0x80370102 is directly linked to Hardware Virtualization not being enabled.** We need more information to help you

Comment: Please provide the output of `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VirtualMachinePlatform`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 10 Update Resolved that issue. It was an Issue in Windows 10 Insider Release.